# POSTMAN - How to create Test using conditional IF with specific expected value for a specific property

Tags: json, postman

I am new to JSON and Postman, and continuing my endeavour thru the learning curve. And I have a question on another simple action.

I have created a GET request which will get a JSON response like the one below.

In the example below I want to create a Test that will Pass only if the (main) "IsArchived" value equals to 'true', otherwise, it should Fail

How can I do it? Thanks in advance

I have already tried the following, but none of those seems to be working.
This one is failing with an error: "response is not defined"

```
pm.test("Value Equal TRUE", function() {
    pm.expect(response.json().IsArchived).to.be.true
});
```

This one always pass, even if I set expected as "=== false" for the response below.

```
pm.test("Item Is Archived", function() {
    if (pm.response.json().IsArchived === true) {
        pm.response.to.have.status(200);
    } 
});
```

Here is my response:

```
{
    "Id": 1328,
    "Name": "AAA Test",
    "Owner": {
        "Id": 208,
        "Name": "The Boss"
    },
    "FieldGroups": [
        {
            "Id": "c81376f0-6ac3-4028-8d61-76a0f815dbf8",
            "Name": "General",
            "FieldDefinitions": [
                {
                    "Id": 1,
                    "DisplayName": "Product Name",
                    "IsArchived": false
                },
                {
                    "Id": 2,
                    "DisplayName": "Short Description",
                    "IsArchived": false
                },
                {
                    "Id": 33,
                    "DisplayName": "Long Description",
                    "IsArchived": false
                },
            ]
        },
        {
            "Id": "5ed8746b-0fa8-4022-8216-ad3af17db91f",
            "Name": "Somethingelse",
            "FieldDefinitions": [
                {
                    "Id": 123,
                     "DisplayName": "Attribution",
                    "IsArchived": false
                },
                {
                    "Id": 1584,
                    "DisplayName": "FC1",
                    "IsArchived": false
                },
                {
                    "Id": 623,
                    "DisplayName": "Sizes",
                    "IsArchived": false,
                    "Owner": {
                        "Id": 208,
                        "Name": "The Boss"
                    },
                    "Unit": "",
                    "Options": [
                        {
                            "Id": 1,
                            "Value": "XS"
                        },
                        {
                            "Id": 2,
                            "Value": "S"
                        },
                        {
                            "Id": 3,
                            "Value": "M"
                        }
                    ]
                }
             ]
        }
    ],
    "IsArchived": false
    "Version": 1
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work.

```
pm.test("Value Equal TRUE", function() {
    pm.expect(pm.response.json().IsArchived).to.be.true
});
```

> "response is not defined"

- error is occuring for missing "pm." in the condition.

I assume that IsArchived element is second last element in the response. If not, you may need to change the hierarchy accordingly.